# Menu token not working sometimes

Tags: users, navigation, tokens

I am using `/user/[current-user:uid]/edit` to generate the user profile setting page where user can edit there profile.
Sometimes it works and sometimes it displays the wrong user id and sometimes I get an error that id not yet assigned.

Drupal: 8
Project: Menu Token
Version: 8.x-1.0-alpha3

Comment: This sounds like your menu item isn't getting cached correctly, it sounds like it doesn't have the right cache contexts.

Comment: It was working fine before. I did not change anything. Can you please explain how i can solve this issue?

Comment: This sounds like a bug that needs to be resolved in the module's issue queue.